# Effective look up between two pandas dataframe using vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, series

I have two pandas dataframe: one is the main data (df1) and the other a look up table (df2).

main data

| Column1 | ... |
| --- | --- |
| [Data 1, Data 2, Data 3, ...] | ... |
| [Data 11, Data 21, Data 31, ...] | ... |

Look up table

| Data | location |
| --- | --- |
| Data1 | location1 |
| Data2 | location2 |
| Data3 | location1 |
| Data11 | location1 |
| ... | ... |

So, my question is how to use pandas vectorization in the main data table to create a new column with this formatting:

| Column1 | ... | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Data 1, Data 2, Data 3, ...] | ... | {location1:[data1,data3], location2:[data2], ....} |
| [Data 11, Data 21, Data 31, ...] | ... | {location1:[Data11], ....} |

I had tried using .apply(axis=1, some lambda function) to create a work around, but it has become inefficient with large entries in the main table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you are trying to accomplish, you want to add a column to the main data shown below as df1.  This column should contain a dictionary with the locations defined in df2 for each entry in the list of the df1 column.

While I have no idea why you need this and certainly would look for a better way to achieve your final objectives, this is how I would proceed:

Given:

```
dt1in = [[['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3']],
        [['Data11', 'Data21', 'Data31']]
        ]
dt2in =[['Data1', 'location1'],
        ['Data2', 'location2'],
        ['Data3', 'location1'],
        ['Data11', 'location1'],
        ['Data21', 'location2'],
        ['Data31', 'location3']
       ]        

import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
df1= pd.DataFrame(data=dt1in, columns=['Col1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dt2in, columns=['Data', 'Location'])
```

The above creates df1 and df2 as shown below:

df1:

```
    Col1
0   [Data1, Data2, Data3]
1   [Data11, Data21, Data31]
```

df2:

```
    Data    Location
0   Data1   location1
1   Data2   location2
2   Data3   location1
3   Data11  location1
4   Data21  location2
5   Data31  location3
```

Then define the function:

```
def buildDict(vals: list, refDF: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    rslt = defaultdict(list)
    for v in vals:
        try:
            loc = refDF[refDF['Data'] == v]['Location'].values[0]
            rslt[v].append(loc)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return rslt
```

Using the buildDict function you can perform the following:

```
df1['Count'] = df1.apply(lambda row: buildDict(row.Col1, df2), axis=1)
```

Which results in modifying df1 as illustrated below:

```
    Col1    Count
0   [Data1, Data2, Data3]   {'Data1': ['location1'], 'Data2': ['location2'...
1   [Data11, Data21, Data31]    {'Data11': ['location1'], 'Data21': ['location...
```